# Trying to override the css of AppBar from React Material Ui,

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, overriding

```
<AppBar className={classes.header}/>
```

The suspect

```
  const classes = useStyles();
```

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    header: {
      borderTop: '10px',
      borderTopColor: '#367BB5'
    },
    grow: {
      flexGrow: 1
    },
    menuButton: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    }
);
```

The grow, and menuButton styling came from the AppBar code directly from Material Ui, but I am trying to implement the header style into the AppBar, unsuccessfully, I have read the documentation but its not very clear to me.

```
export default Header;
```

EDIT:

The docs say that the `Style sheet name: MuiAppBar` but whenever I change header to that, it doesn't change anything

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles({
      root: {
        position: 'static', // doesnt work
        borderTop: '100px', // doesnt work
        borderTopColor: '#367BB5', // doesnt work
        backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
      },
    })
```

```
      <AppBar position="static" classes={{ root: classes.root }}>
```

Doing this allows me to change the backgroundColor, but the other properties don't work. Not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important that you follow this page: https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/
You need to use the `ThemeProvider` in order to custom the style.

Comment: I've tried checking out that page, was not very clear to me, have tried to use it with no success, which is why I am asking

Comment: I see. Relax we are here to help. I didn't see ThemeProvider in your code. Let's try to do something that put us in the same context. This is exactly what we have as example on the page. https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-antonelli-7k27d
What you are try to do is override the globals and you're missing the concept.

Comment: Sorry if i came off as hostile, checking your sandbox for example. how would you add in my root css properties onto an AppBar component? I will try and edit a post of some code showing what I have in a minute

Comment: No problem. For instance, you want to change the background. Use the overrides key: `overrides: {
    MuiAppBar: {
      colorPrimary: {
        backgroundColor: yellow.A700
      }
    }
  },` check the codesandbox

Comment: Thanks, how would you go about adding other properties such as border-top, and border-top-color? My problem is that I can't find these properties in the documentation of whats allowed and what isn't.

Comment: Would it be something like `overrides: { MuiAppBar: { colorPrimary: { backgroundColor: yellow.A700 },root: { border-top: '10px' } } },`

Comment: Please, if this is your response. Don't forget to vote. We are helping to get points! 
`overrides: {
    MuiAppBar: {
      colorPrimary: {
        backgroundColor: yellow.A700
      },
      root: {
        border: 0,
        borderTop: 10,
        borderTopColor: orange[500],
        borderTopStyle: "solid"
      }
    }
  },`

Comment: I just wanted to see if it worked before I marked as answer! Which it does, thank you so much! how would you go about targeting like an <h1> inside of AppBar?

Comment: Inside the appBar? I didn't see it a lot, but I think you can explore the examples on their page. But you could change the title by this:  `<Typography variant="h1" className={classes.title}>
          News
        </Typography>`